# Google Search on Page (Remove Paging)

Tags: asp.net, paging, google-search

I am using Google Custom Search and showing result on my website, but with results its also showing paging.

Please tell me how to control number of rows in search result and remove paging from it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe that Google would send you millions of results in a single request.

You can though control the number of results you're getting (from 10 to 100) in each page. See [API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/using_rest.html#opt-query-params).